# How can I disable font-lock-mode but have the whitespace mode highlighting

Tags: font-lock, whitespace-mode

Is there any way to disable syntax highlighting of the buffer (which I do by disabling the `font-lock-mode`) and having the trailing whitespaces highlighted in red? or at least show a unicode dot?

(When I disable the `font-lock-mode`, it also disables the highlighting for the whitespace mode.)

Answer (score 2):

> having the trailing whitespaces highlighted in red

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `show-trailing-whitespace` does not depend upon `font-lock-mode`.

Enabling that and disabling font-lock-mode is fine, AFAICS.

Parts of `whitespace-mode` also work without font-lock-mode being enabled.

> show a unicode dot

```
(setq whitespace-style '(space-mark))
```

Comment: setting that variable only does not give it a color as I tested it with `emacs -Q`. `(setq whitespace-style '(space-mark))` shows a dot for all spaces, whereas I only want the _trailing_ whitespaces to be marked as dot.

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem with `show-trailing-whitespace`.  It 100% works under `emacs -Q` for me.  It uses the `trailing-whitespace` face, which has a red background by default.